# I am trying to create a changing background color. Is there any way i can create a delay between the switching?

Tags: ios, swift

```
backround.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
//Delay code ?
backround.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

Is there anyway to do this? I do not know the exact code line to create this type of delay.

Comment: Do you want it to continuously switch between two colours? Or only change once?

Comment: This is an excellent delay function you can use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/1305067

Comment: I am trying to continuously change it but I know how to create loops I just don't know how to delay it

Comment: Do you want it to blend from red to blue or go straight from red to blue?

Comment: You code always use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/6807081) method and improt your code in the proper

Answer (score 0):

```
func performDelayBlock(block:() -> Void, afterDelay delay:NSTimeInterval)
{
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)
}
```

usage:

```
backround.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
performDelayBlock({ 
    self.backround.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    }, afterDelay: 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using NSTimer.

```
//Register for NSTimer wherever you are setting your first color and then set the interval time. 
//Since you want to repeat you can just do repeat to be true 
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "changeBackground", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)




func changeBackground() {
    backround.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() //whichever you like
   //Have conditional code to change it back and forth to red and other color you want to.
}
```